# How Count Array

Tags: php, arrays, count

If array with 2 keys:

```
Array(
[0] => content
[1] => content
)
```

It is a task

if array 3 keys

```
Array(
[0] => content
[1] => content
[2] => content
)
```

It is other task

How count how many keys (`[0], [1]`..) there are in the array?

I already have all the structure of the code but just need to know how to know the amount of keys within the variable that contains the array

Comment: Putting your own title into google would be a start

Comment: [count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).... PHP Is one of the best documented languages around, learn to use those docs

Comment: `echo count($array);` ???

Comment: @MarkBaker I not understand using it example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count_values.asp

Comment: @devpro I understand, thank you

Comment: Array count value will return the COUNT OF SAME VALUE IN ARRAY

Comment: In your example it will return `array("content"=>2)`

Comment: Don't use w3schools, use [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/).... that's the official documentation, and very details with plenty of examples as well

Comment: Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$len = count($myArray);`

I think this is what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment if you are using [array_count_values()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count_values.asp)  it will return the array that contains no of count of same values.

```
$yourArr = array("content","content");
print_r( array_count_values($yourArr) );
```

**Result**:

```
array("content"=>2);
```

[From W3School:](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count_values.asp)

Returns an associative array, where the keys are the original array's values, and the values are the number of occurrences

Comment: Thank you @devpro, I learned something new thank you

Comment: @gislef always use Php manual instead of others